# Python multi-threaded work on list

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

I need to parse a large amount of URLs in a list. Every iteration is time expensive and I prefer to make it in several threads. Is it safe to do `for` loop where each iteration starts a new thread with its position or I must split the list and send the tasks separately(new to python, I know this is not the case but still...). I just want to avoid any kind of thread collision. Thanks in advance!

```
#This is what i have so far:
ignore_list = []
counter = 0
for index in results:
    sail = index['d']['ResultItems']
    for rw in sail:
        destination = match_by_meta(index['d']['ErrorMessage'])
        destination_code = destination[1]
        destination_name = destination[0]
        code = rw['VirtualItineraryCode']
        cruise_line_name = "Costa Cruises"
        number_of_nights = rw['Duration']
        vessel_name = rw['Ship']
        vessel_id = get_vessel_id(vessel_name)
        cruise_id = "4"
        brochure_name = rw['Description']
        itinerary_url = rw['CruiseDetailURL']
        for sailing in rw['AllCruiseInfo']:
            itinerary_id = sailing['CruiseCode']
            if itinerary_id in doubles:
                continue
            else:
                doubles.append(itinerary_id)
                counter += 1
            sail_date = sailing['DepartureDateFormatted']
            print(counter, brochure_name)
            return_date = calculate_days(sail_date, number_of_nights)
            cruise_url = build_cruise_url(itinerary_url, itinerary_id)
            prices = get_prices(cruise_url)
            interior_bucket_price = prices[0]
            ocean_view_bucket_price = prices[1]
            balcony_bucket_price = prices[2]
            suite_bucket_price = prices[3]
            special = False
            temp = [destination_code, destination_name, vessel_id, vessel_name, cruise_id,
                    cruise_line_name,
                    itinerary_id, brochure_name, number_of_nights, sail_date, return_date,
                    interior_bucket_price, ocean_view_bucket_price, balcony_bucket_price,
                    suite_bucket_price]
            if "Costa Deliziosa" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['11/27/2015', '12/20/2015'], ['11/27/2015', '12/28/2015'], ['12/2/2015', '12/20/2015'],
                         ['12/2/2015', '12/21/2015'], ['12/2/2015', '12/28/2015'], ['11/27/2016', '12/28/2016'],
                         ['12/1/2016', '12/21/2016'], ['12/2/2016', '12/21/2016'], ['12/2/2016', '12/28/2016'],
                         ['3/8/2017', '4/5/2017'], ['3/8/2017', '4/9/2017'], ['3/18/2017', '4/5/2017']]
                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif 'Costa Diadema' in vessel_name:
                dates = [['12/10/2015', '12/17/2015'], ['12/17/2015', '12/24/2015'], ['12/24/2015', '12/31/2015'],
                         ['1/7/2016', '1/14/2016'], ['1/14/2016', '1/21/2016'], ['1/21/2016', '1/28/2016'],
                         ['1/28/2016', '2/4/2016'], ['2/4/2016', '2/11/2016'], ['2/11/2016', '2/18/2016'],
                         ['2/18/2016', '2/25/2016'], ['2/25/2016', '3/3/2016'], ['3/3/2016', '3/10/2016'],
                         ['3/10/2016', '3/17/2016'], ['3/17/2016', '3/24/2016'], ['4/7/2016', '4/14/2016'],
                         ['4/14/2016', '4/21/2016'], ['4/21/2016', '4/28/2016'], ['4/28/2016', '5/5/2016'],
                         ['5/5/2016', '5/12/2016'], ['5/12/2016', '5/19/2016'], ['5/19/2016', '5/26/2016'],
                         ['5/26/2016', '6/2/2016'], ['6/2/2016', '6/9/2016'], ['6/9/2016', '6/16/2016'],
                         ['6/16/2016', '6/23/2016'], ['6/17/2016', '6/24/2016'], ['6/23/2016', '6/30/2016'],
                         ['6/24/2016', '7/1/2016'], ['6/30/2016', '7/7/2016'], ['7/1/2016', '7/8/2016'],
                         ['7/7/2016', '7/14/2016'], ['7/8/2016', '7/15/2016'], ['7/14/2016', '7/21/2016'],
                         ['7/15/2016', '7/22/2016'], ['7/21/2016', '7/28/2016'], ['7/22/2016', '7/29/2016'],
                         ['7/28/2016', '8/4/2016'], ['7/29/2016', '8/5/2016'], ['8/4/2016', '8/11/2016'],
                         ['8/5/2016', '8/12/2016'], ['8/11/2016', '8/18/2016'], ['8/12/2016', '8/19/2016'],
                         ['8/18/2016', '8/25/2016'], ['8/19/2016', '8/26/2016'], ['8/25/2016', '9/1/2016'],
                         ['8/26/2016', '9/2/2016'], ['9/1/2016', '9/8/2016'], ['9/2/2016', '9/9/2016'],
                         ['9/8/2016', '9/15/2016'], ['9/9/2016', '9/16/2016'], ['9/15/2016', '9/22/2016'],
                         ['9/22/2016', '9/29/2016'], ['9/29/2016', '10/6/2016'], ['10/6/2016', '10/13/2016'],
                         ['10/13/2016', '10/20/2016'], ['10/20/2016', '10/27/2016'], ['10/27/2016', '11/3/2016'],
                         ['11/3/2016', '11/10/2016'], ['11/10/2016', '11/17/2016'], ['11/17/2016', '11/24/2016'],
                         ['11/24/2016', '12/1/2016'], ['1/5/2017', '1/12/2017'], ['1/12/2017', '1/19/2017'],
                         ['1/19/2017', '1/26/2017'], ['1/26/2017', '2/2/2017'], ['1/30/2017', '2/6/2017'],
                         ['2/2/2017', '2/9/2017'], ['2/9/2017', '2/16/2017'], ['2/16/2017', '2/23/2017'],
                         ['2/23/2017', '3/2/2017'], ['3/2/2017', '3/9/2017'], ['3/9/2017', '3/16/2017'],
                         ['3/16/2017', '3/23/2017'], ['3/23/2017', '3/30/2017'], ['3/30/2017', '4/6/2017'],
                         ['4/6/2017', '4/13/2017'], ['4/13/2017', '4/20/2017'], ['4/20/2017', '4/27/2017'],
                         ['4/27/2017', '5/4/2017'], ['5/4/2017', '5/11/2017'], ['5/11/2017', '5/18/2017'],
                         ['5/18/2017', '5/25/2017'], ['6/2/2017', '6/9/2017'], ['6/9/2017', '6/16/2017'],
                         ['6/16/2017', '6/23/2017'], ['6/23/2017', '6/30/2017'], ['6/30/2017', '7/7/2017'],
                         ['7/7/2017', '7/14/2017'], ['7/14/2017', '7/21/2017'], ['7/21/2017', '7/28/2017'],
                         ['7/28/2017', '8/4/2017'], ['8/4/2017', '8/11/2017'], ['8/11/2017', '8/18/2017'],
                         ['8/18/2017', '8/25/2017'], ['8/25/2017', '9/1/2017'], ['9/1/2017', '9/8/2017'],
                         ['9/8/2017', '9/15/2017'], ['9/15/2017', '9/22/2017'], ['9/22/2017', '9/29/2017'],
                         ['10/5/2017', '10/12/2017'], ['10/12/2017', '10/19/2017'], ['10/19/2017', '10/26/2017'],
                         ['10/26/2017', '11/2/2017'], ['11/2/2017', '11/9/2017'], ['11/9/2017', '11/16/2017'],
                         ['11/16/2017', '11/23/2017'], ['11/23/2017', '11/30/2017'], ['11/30/2017', '12/7/2017'],
                         ['12/9/2017', '12/16/2017'], ['12/16/2017', '12/22/2017'], ['12/22/2017', '12/29/2017'],
                         ['12/29/2017', '1/6/2018'], ['1/6/2018', '1/13/2018'], ['1/13/2018', '1/20/2018'],
                         ['1/20/2018', '1/27/2018'], ['2/1/2018', '2/8/2018'], ['2/8/2018', '2/15/2018'],
                         ['2/15/2018', '2/22/2018'], ['2/22/2018', '3/1/2018'], ['3/1/2018', '3/8/2018'],
                         ['3/8/2018', '3/15/2018'], ['3/15/2018', '3/22/2018'], ['3/22/2018', '3/29/2018'],
                         ['3/29/2018', '4/5/2018']]
                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Fascinosa" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['10/3/2015', '10/10/2015'], ['10/10/2015', '10/17/2015'], ['10/17/2015', '10/24/2015'],
                         ['10/24/2015', '10/31/2015'], ['10/31/2015', '11/7/2015'], ['11/7/2015', '11/14/2015'],
                         ['11/9/2015', '11/16/2015'], ['11/14/2015', '11/21/2015'], ['11/15/2015', '11/22/2015'],
                         ['11/21/2015', '11/28/2015'], ['3/20/2016', '3/27/2016'], ['3/27/2016', '4/3/2016'],
                         ['4/3/2016', '4/10/2016'], ['4/10/2016', '4/17/2016'], ['4/17/2016', '4/24/2016'],
                         ['4/24/2016', '5/1/2016'], ['5/1/2016', '5/8/2016'], ['5/8/2016', '5/15/2016'],
                         ['5/15/2016', '5/22/2016'], ['5/22/2016', '5/29/2016'], ['5/29/2016', '6/5/2016'],
                         ['6/5/2016', '6/12/2016'], ['6/12/2016', '6/19/2016'], ['6/19/2016', '6/26/2016'],
                         ['6/26/2016', '7/3/2016'], ['7/3/2016', '7/10/2016'], ['7/10/2016', '7/17/2016'],
                         ['7/17/2016', '7/24/2016'], ['7/24/2016', '7/31/2016'], ['7/31/2016', '8/7/2016'],
                         ['8/7/2016', '8/14/2016'], ['8/14/2016', '8/21/2016'], ['8/21/2016', '8/28/2016'],
                         ['8/28/2016', '9/4/2016'], ['9/4/2016', '9/11/2016'], ['9/11/2016', '9/18/2016'],
                         ['9/18/2016', '9/25/2016'], ['9/25/2016', '10/2/2016'], ['10/2/2016', '10/9/2016'],
                         ['10/9/2016', '10/16/2016'], ['10/16/2016', '10/23/2016'], ['10/23/2016', '10/30/2016'],
                         ['10/30/2016', '11/6/2016'], ['11/6/2016', '11/13/2016'], ['11/13/2016', '11/20/2016'],
                         ['11/20/2016', '11/27/2016'], ['11/27/2016', '12/2/2016'], ['11/27/2016', '12/4/2016'],
                         ['12/11/2016', '12/22/2016'], ['12/22/2016', '12/27/2016'], ['12/27/2016', '1/7/2017'],
                         ['1/7/2017', '1/18/2017'], ['1/18/2017', '1/29/2017'], ['1/28/2017', '2/4/2017'],
                         ['2/4/2017', '2/11/2017'], ['2/11/2017', '2/18/2017'], ['2/18/2017', '2/25/2017'],
                         ['2/25/2017', '3/4/2017'], ['3/4/2017', '3/11/2017'], ['3/11/2017', '3/18/2017'],
                         ['3/18/2017', '3/25/2017'], ['3/19/2017', '3/26/2017'], ['3/26/2017', '4/2/2017'],
                         ['4/2/2017', '4/9/2017'], ['4/7/2017', '4/14/2017'], ['4/14/2017', '4/21/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Favolosa" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['10/1/2015', '10/8/2015'], ['10/8/2015', '10/15/2015'], ['10/15/2015', '10/22/2015'],
                         ['10/22/2015', '10/29/2015'], ['10/29/2015', '11/5/2015'], ['11/5/2015', '11/12/2015'],
                         ['11/12/2015', '11/19/2015'], ['11/19/2015', '11/26/2015'], ['9/13/2016', '9/22/2016'],
                         ['9/22/2016', '10/1/2016'], ['10/1/2016', '10/10/2016'], ['10/10/2016', '10/19/2016'],
                         ['10/19/2016', '10/23/2016'], ['10/23/2016', '10/28/2016'], ['10/28/2016', '11/2/2016'],
                         ['11/2/2016', '11/7/2016'], ['11/7/2016', '11/12/2016'], ['11/12/2016', '11/17/2016'],
                         ['4/15/2017', '4/19/2017'], ['4/19/2017', '4/22/2017'], ['4/22/2017', '4/26/2017'],
                         ['4/26/2017', '4/29/2017'], ['4/29/2017', '5/3/2017'], ['5/3/2017', '5/8/2017'],
                         ['5/8/2017', '5/11/2017'], ['5/11/2017', '5/15/2017'], ['5/15/2017', '5/26/2017'],
                         ['5/26/2017', '6/2/2017'], ['6/2/2017', '6/9/2017'], ['6/9/2017', '6/16/2017'],
                         ['6/16/2017', '6/23/2017'], ['6/23/2017', '6/30/2017'], ['6/30/2017', '7/7/2017'],
                         ['7/7/2017', '7/14/2017'], ['7/14/2017', '7/21/2017'], ['7/21/2017', '7/28/2017'],
                         ['7/28/2017', '8/4/2017'], ['8/4/2017', '8/11/2017'], ['8/11/2017', '8/18/2017'],
                         ['8/18/2017', '8/25/2017'], ['8/25/2017', '9/1/2017'], ['9/1/2017', '9/8/2017'],
                         ['9/8/2017', '9/20/2017'], ['9/21/2017', '9/26/2017'], ['9/26/2017', '10/1/2017'],
                         ['10/1/2017', '10/6/2017'], ['10/6/2017', '10/11/2017'], ['10/16/2017', '10/21/2017'],
                         ['10/21/2017', '10/26/2017'], ['10/26/2017', '10/31/2017'], ['10/31/2017', '11/5/2017'],
                         ['11/5/2017', '11/10/2017'], ['11/9/2017', '11/14/2017'], ['11/10/2017', '11/15/2017'],
                         ['11/14/2017', '11/19/2017'], ['11/15/2017', '11/20/2017'], ['11/19/2017', '11/24/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Luminosa" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['12/27/2015', '1/5/2016'], ['12/24/2016', '12/31/2016'], ['12/31/2016', '1/6/2017']]
                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Magica" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['12/12/2015', '12/19/2015'], ['12/19/2015', '12/26/2015'], ['12/26/2015', '1/2/2016'],
                         ['1/2/2016', '1/9/2016'], ['1/9/2016', '1/16/2016'], ['1/16/2016', '1/23/2016'],
                         ['1/23/2016', '1/30/2016'], ['1/30/2016', '2/6/2016'], ['2/6/2016', '2/13/2016'],
                         ['2/13/2016', '2/20/2016'], ['2/20/2016', '2/27/2016'], ['2/27/2016', '3/5/2016'],
                         ['3/5/2016', '3/12/2016'], ['3/6/2016', '3/20/2016'], ['3/12/2016', '3/19/2016'],
                         ['3/19/2016', '3/26/2016'], ['5/19/2017', '5/31/2017'], ['6/9/2017', '6/18/2017'],
                         ['6/18/2017', '7/2/2017'], ['7/11/2017', '7/20/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    for d in dates:
                        if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                            special = True
                            break
                        else:
                            special = False
            elif "Costa Mediterranea" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['11/13/2015', '11/20/2015'], ['1/3/2017', '1/9/2017'], ['1/21/2017', '2/3/2017'],
                         ['2/3/2017', '2/10/2017'], ['2/10/2017', '2/17/2017'], ['2/17/2017', '2/24/2017'],
                         ['2/24/2017', '3/3/2017'], ['3/3/2017', '3/10/2017'], ['3/10/2017', '3/17/2017'],
                         ['3/17/2017', '3/24/2017'], ['3/24/2017', '3/31/2017'], ['3/31/2017', '4/3/2017'],
                         ['4/2/2017', '4/5/2017'], ['4/15/2017', '4/20/2017'], ['4/30/2017', '5/10/2017'],
                         ['10/4/2017', '10/14/2017'], ['10/14/2017', '10/24/2017'], ['10/24/2017', '11/3/2017'],
                         ['11/3/2017', '11/13/2017'], ['11/24/2017', '12/15/2017'], ['11/24/2017', '12/16/2017'],
                         ['12/16/2017', '12/23/2017'], ['12/23/2017', '12/30/2017'], ['12/30/2017', '1/6/2018'],
                         ['1/6/2018', '1/13/2018'], ['1/20/2018', '1/27/2018'], ['1/27/2018', '2/3/2018'],
                         ['2/3/2018', '2/10/2018'], ['2/10/2018', '2/17/2018'], ['2/17/2018', '2/24/2018'],
                         ['2/24/2018', '3/3/2018']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa neoClassica" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['10/8/2015', '10/18/2015'], ['10/18/2015', '10/28/2015'], ['10/28/2015', '11/7/2015'],
                         ['11/2/2015', '11/16/2015'], ['11/7/2015', '11/17/2015'], ['11/9/2015', '11/23/2015'],
                         ['3/25/2017', '4/14/2017'], ['11/17/2015', '12/14/2015'], ['11/27/2016', '12/20/2016'],
                         ['12/20/2016', '12/27/2016'], ['12/27/2016', '1/3/2017'], ['1/3/2017', '1/10/2017'],
                         ['1/10/2017', '1/31/2017'], ['1/31/2017', '2/21/2017'], ['2/21/2017', '3/14/2017'],
                         ['3/14/2017', '4/8/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa neoRomantica" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['11/17/2015', '11/29/2015'], ['11/17/2015', '12/12/2015'], ['3/29/2016', '4/13/2016'],
                         ['4/13/2016', '4/28/2016'], ['4/28/2016', '5/13/2016'], ['9/15/2016', '9/26/2016'],
                         ['9/15/2016', '10/15/2016'], ['9/17/2016', '9/28/2016'], ['9/26/2016', '10/7/2016'],
                         ['9/28/2016', '10/9/2016'], ['10/7/2016', '10/18/2016'], ['10/18/2016', '10/29/2016'],
                         ['10/20/2016', '10/31/2016'], ['10/29/2016', '11/9/2016'], ['10/31/2016', '11/11/2016'],
                         ['11/9/2016', '11/20/2016'], ['11/11/2016', '11/22/2016'], ['11/20/2016', '12/1/2016'],
                         ['3/4/2017', '3/31/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Pacifica" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['9/29/2015', '10/10/2015'], ['10/21/2015', '11/1/2015'], ['11/12/2015', '11/23/2015'],
                         ['11/28/2015', '12/16/2015'], ['3/26/2016', '4/2/2016'], ['4/2/2016', '4/9/2016'],
                         ['4/9/2016', '4/16/2016'], ['4/16/2016', '4/23/2016'], ['4/23/2016', '4/30/2016'],
                         ['4/30/2016', '5/7/2016'], ['9/24/2016', '10/1/2016'], ['10/1/2016', '10/8/2016'],
                         ['10/8/2016', '10/15/2016'], ['10/15/2016', '10/22/2016'], ['10/22/2016', '10/29/2016'],
                         ['10/29/2016', '11/5/2016'], ['11/5/2016', '11/12/2016'], ['11/12/2016', '11/19/2016'],
                         ['11/19/2016', '11/26/2016'], ['11/27/2016', '12/12/2016'], ['11/27/2016', '12/13/2016'],
                         ['2/25/2017', '3/17/2017'], ['3/2/2017', '3/17/2017'], ['3/2/2017', '3/19/2017'],
                         ['3/25/2017', '4/1/2017'], ['4/1/2017', '4/8/2017'], ['4/8/2017', '4/15/2017'],
                         ['4/15/2017', '4/22/2017'], ['4/22/2017', '4/29/2017'], ['4/29/2017', '5/6/2017'],
                         ['5/6/2017', '5/13/2017'], ['5/13/2017', '5/20/2017'], ['5/20/2017', '6/1/2017'],
                         ['9/30/2017', '10/7/2017'], ['10/7/2017', '10/14/2017'], ['10/14/2017', '10/21/2017'],
                         ['10/21/2017', '10/28/2017'], ['10/28/2017', '11/4/2017'], ['11/4/2017', '11/11/2017'],
                         ['11/11/2017', '11/18/2017']]

                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            elif "Costa Classica" in vessel_name:
                dates = [['11/6/2015', '11/17/2015']]
                for d in dates:
                    if sail_date == d[0] and return_date == d[1]:
                        special = True
                        break
                    else:
                        special = False
            if special:
                temp = [destination_code, destination_name, vessel_id, vessel_name, cruise_id,
                        cruise_line_name,
                        itinerary_id, brochure_name, number_of_nights, sail_date, return_date,
                        interior_bucket_price, ocean_view_bucket_price, balcony_bucket_price,
                        suite_bucket_price]
                ignore_list.append(temp)
            else:
                temp = [destination_code, destination_name, vessel_id, vessel_name, cruise_id,
                        cruise_line_name,
                        itinerary_id, brochure_name, number_of_nights, sail_date, return_date,
                        interior_bucket_price, ocean_view_bucket_price, balcony_bucket_price,
                        suite_bucket_price]
                to_write.append(temp)
def calculate_days(sail_date_param, number_of_nights_param):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sail_date_param, "%m/%d/%Y")
    try:
        calculated = date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(number_of_nights_param))
    except ValueError:
        calculated = date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(number_of_nights_param.split("-")[1]))
    calculated = calculated.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    return calculated


def build_cruise_url(ur, co):
    split = ur.split("-")
    return 'http://www.costacruise.com' + split[0] + '-' + split[1] + '-' + co + '.html'


def get_prices(link):
    interior_bucket_price1 = "N/A"
    ocean_view_bucket_price1 = "N/A"
    balcony_bucket_price1 = "N/A"
    suite_bucket_price1 = "N/A"
    spans = []
    price_page = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(price_page.text, 'lxml')
    for r in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "cabins clearfix"}):
        children = r.find_all("div", {"class": "wrap"})
        for child in children:
            item = child.text.strip().split('from')
            spans.append(item)
    for i in range(0, len(spans)):
        if spans[i][0].strip() == "Inside":
            interior_bucket_price1 = spans[i][1].split('$')[1]
        if spans[i][0].strip() == "Outside" or spans[i][0].strip() == 'Ocean View' or spans[i][
            0].strip() == 'Oceanview':
            ocean_view_bucket_price1 = spans[i][1].split('$')[1]
        if spans[i][0].strip() == "Veranda" or spans[i][0].strip() == "Ocean View Balcony":
            balcony_bucket_price1 = spans[i][1].split('$')[1]
        if spans[i][0].strip() == "Suites" or spans[i][0].strip() == "Suite":
            suite_bucket_price1 = spans[i][1].split('$')[1]
    if interior_bucket_price1 != "N/A":
        if "," in interior_bucket_price1:
            interior_bucket_price1 = interior_bucket_price1.replace(",", "")
        else:
            pass
        interior_bucket_price1 = str(int(math.ceil(float(interior_bucket_price1))))
    else:
        pass
    if ocean_view_bucket_price1 != "N/A":
        if "," in ocean_view_bucket_price1:
            ocean_view_bucket_price1 = ocean_view_bucket_price1.replace(",", "")
        else:
            pass
        ocean_view_bucket_price1 = str(
            int(math.ceil(float(ocean_view_bucket_price1))))
    else:
        pass
    if balcony_bucket_price1 != "N/A":
        if "," in balcony_bucket_price1:
            balcony_bucket_price1 = balcony_bucket_price1.replace(",", "")
        else:
            pass
        balcony_bucket_price1 = str(int(math.ceil(float(balcony_bucket_price1))))
    else:
        pass
    if suite_bucket_price1 != "N/A":
        if "," in suite_bucket_price1:
            suite_bucket_price1 = suite_bucket_price1.replace(",", "")
        else:
            pass
        suite_bucket_price1 = str(int(math.ceil(float(suite_bucket_price1))))
    else:
        pass
    return [interior_bucket_price1, ocean_view_bucket_price1, balcony_bucket_price1, suite_bucket_price1]


def match_by_meta(param):
    # print(param)
    if param == "ATLANTIC OCEAN":
        result = ['Atlantic Ocean', 'AO']
        return result

    elif param == "EASTERN CARIBBEAN":
        result = ['Carib', 'C']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "MAR ROSSOARAB":
        result = ['Exotics', 'D']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "EAST MEDITERRANEAN":
        result = ['Europe', 'EM']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "ORIENTAL LANDS":
        result = ['Exotics', 'FE']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "GREATEASTERNCRUISES":
        result = ['Exotics', 'ML']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "INDIAN OCEAN":
        result = ['Exotics', 'MU']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "NORTHERN CAPITALS":
        result = ['Europe', 'NC']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "NORWEGIAN FJORDS":
        result = ['Europe', 'NJ']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "PACIFIC OCEAN":
        result = ['South Pacific', 'SP']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "MAR ROSSO":
        result = ['Exotics', 'RS']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "SOUTH AMERICA":
        result = ['South America', 'S']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "TRANSATLANTIC":
        result = ['Europe', 'X']
        # print(result)
        return result

    elif param == "WEST MEDITERRANEAN":
        result = ['Europe', 'WM']
        # print(result)
        return result


def get_vessel_id(ves_name):
    if ves_name == "Costa Deliziosa":
        return "713"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Diadema":
        return "858"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Fascinosa":
        return "755"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Favolosa":
        return "728"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Luminosa":
        return "683"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Magica":
        return "437"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Mediterranea":
        return "425"
    elif ves_name == "Costa neoClassica":
        return "403"
    elif ves_name == "Costa neoRiviera":
        return "881"
    elif ves_name == "Costa neoRomantica":
        return "79"
    elif ves_name == "Costa Pacifica":
        return "684"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can make use of the map function and the multi-threading library as mentioned [here](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/).

Comment: Yeah, it's the most elegant thing i've ever seen.

Comment: do you know if i run this from some UI will it block the main thread?

Comment: How exactly do you plan on running it? Can you give me more details?

Comment: lets say just a button that starts downloading things and saves them in DB.

Comment: If you're using a GUI to call the function it shouldn't affect the GIL: the functionality is still the same, correct? You're only changing the event that triggers the code to run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134110/discussion-between-fruitspunchsamurai-and-nephilimrising).